# Html/CSS results page / scorecard for cricket in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-table

I'm new to web-design and in process of creating a sports website based on the WordPress platform.

One of the sports that the site will be covering is cricket. My site is almost done, but I'm stuck at few very important CSS/Html tables for data. I would really appreciate if someone here could guide/help me on how to create tables like the ones in the links bellow or whether there is anyway someone can copy html/css from an existing site and style it.

[I just need a copy of the tables, sorting options are not needed](http://www.dpltwenty20.com/results#.URgKm6WzKSo)

[Similar scorecard as light as possible would be great](http://www.pcb.com.pk/match/24717.html)

Are these things possible with CSS/html in Wordpress or is there any better option for such tables?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions you could use:

**Solution #1:** [TabPress Plugin](http://tablepress.org/demo/)

Through a graphical panel, you can fully customize your table. You can set your own CSS, you can have colspan, rowspan or all together.  Check out the [demo](http://tablepress.org/demo/). If you don't want to spend too much time in coding, give it a try.

**Solution #2:** [WP_List_Table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table)

It's available since WordPress 3.1. WP 3.1 uses it to build the tables you can see in the admin panel. The table who displays the posts for instance uses this class. However, you can disable some features such as sorting, bulk operations etc.

Here is a sample code taken from one of my blogs. I wanted to display a table of statistics with no sorting option. Call `ff_show_stats()` to display the table from your PHP code.

```
if( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class FFStatsTable extends WP_List_Table {
    function __construct(){

    }

    function get_columns(){
        $columns = array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'creation' => 'Creation',
            'country' => 'Country'
            // Add as much column as you want
            // 'column_name_in_query' => 'Displayed column name' 
        );
        return $columns;
    }

    function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
        switch( $column_name ) { 
        case 'id':
        case 'creation':
        case 'country':
            return $item[ $column_name ];
        default:
            return print_r( $item, true ) ; //Show the whole array for debugging purposes
        }
    }

    function prepare_items() {
        global $wpdb;

        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = array();//Empty array for disabling sorting
        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);

        $this->items = $wpdb->get_results(
            "SELECT id,creation,country FROM wp_my_table WHERE my_condtion=TRUE",
            ARRAY_A 
        );
    }    
}

function ff_show_stats() {
    $myListTable = new FFStatsTable();

    echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>Stats</h2>'; 
    $myListTable->prepare_items(); 
    $myListTable->display(); 
    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

You can have a more detailed sample code here : http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/custom-list-table-example/tags/1.2/list-table-example.php

Comment: Thanks Stephan, 
I have very little coding knowledge, I've now installed the TabPress Plugin, but I can't figure how it will enable me to create a scorecard as the above sample. 

The results rows looks possible, but again how do I add images into it